# How can I allocate a large contiguous memory chunk in C# (win + linux)

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, mono

I'm searching for a memory allocation method in C# that provides a contiguous chunk of memory (> 4 GiB). This method should work on Mono as well as on Microsoft .NET. It's no problem if this memory is unmanaged.

**Linux:**
I think calling mmap by DllImport is a good choice for Mono.

**Windows:**
I found several method's like HeapAlloc, AllocHGlobal, ..., but none of them seem to provide a 64 bit size parameter.

There is also a method to enable large object for the GC. Are these objects contiguous?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about why you need 4 GB of contiguous memory? There must *surely* be a better way.

Comment: The Memory Mapped File API uses Int64 everywhere. No telling if it meets your needs though.

Comment: This code is part of a hardware emulator. We have already a Java implementation. We are now evaluating to port our code to Mone/.NET

Comment: @Paebbels That sounds like a task that would be better suited for a C++ implementation, as you'll have far greater power to maninpuate memory at a very fine level of detail.  You could then create a C# (or Java or other managed language) wrapper for the program to allow it to be more easily accessed from managed languages.

Comment: Trust me,we know what we are doing at university :) Using an intermediate language with dyn. byte code execution is an interesting idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` has an `IntPtr` version, which can support 64-bit values.

What makes you say it doesn't.

Comment: This [manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5cyb68cy(v=vs.110).aspx) has contradictory parameter descriptions: Summary: `... by using the pointer to the specified number of bytes.` Parameter description: `cb - The required number of bytes in memory.` Where can I find what type and value range can be used for the parameter? AllocHGlobal calls LocalAlloc which is also [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa366723.aspx). AllocHGlobal has 2 overloads, one of them supports only Int32. So I can't find any guaranty that IntPtr is allowed to point to an Int64.

Comment: @Paebbels: I just did a little searching on this and found it is hard to find information. However, I can see that `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` is overloaded and one version accepts an `IntPtr`, which is capable of holding 64-bit values (as I indicated in my answer). Did you try using `IntPtr`? Did you try it with a larger value?